# Can you identify this military uniform? Montana 1850-1920

Tags: military, war, identification, uniform

[image: Portrait of man in uniform with slouch hat]

Portrait taken in Montana-best guess between 1850 and 1920. WWI??  Slouch hat. Single-breasted coat with 5 or 6 buttons. Breast pocket on each side; diagonal, flap with button. Knee-high boots. Curvy double-lines of embroidery above sleeve cuffs. Soldier formally posed sitting on tree stumps with hands on thighs, left foot/knee higher up (resting on stump part), lattice fence in right background.
    This is one of the few photographs from my husband's family. Could it be a Forest Service uniform? Civil war? WWI?
   Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Civil War seems too early, to me, and WWI possibly too late. It looks vaguely like a "Rough Rider" uniform, as in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodbury_Kane#/media/File:Woodbury_kane_from_rough_riders_by_theodore_roosevelt_pg_153.jpg .

Comment: I higher resolution scan would help. I can see there is something on the hat but can't make it out, similarly with the watermark at the bottom.

Comment: IMHO a dark blue jacket would usually look darker than the jacket in this photo.  Therefore I suppose that the picture dates from after roughly 1898 when the US army adopted khaki uniforms, unless this is some other type of uniform like National Guard that might have changed colors at a different date.  As I recall, by WWI the US army, if this is a US army uniform, adopted a different style of hat, so it is possible that the likely time period is less than 2 decades.

Comment: This PDF seems like a good place to start research on Army uniforms.  Note that the hat in the photo seems to me to be an earlier design than the 1911 model service hat seen on page 59.  https://history.army.mil/html/museums/uniforms/survey_uwa.pdf